# How to retrieve End-of-Line from a div content editable in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So Basically I have:

```
 <div id="hey" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Which is used as a Text Box. Now the problem is that when you Try inputting something like:

```
Hello
How are you
```

(Notice: it contains an End-of-Line after hello). But the output I'm getting is as `HelloHow are you` But I want it to be as

```
Hello
How are you
```

Jsfiddle Test: https://jsfiddle.net/zcyg8q2u/

You can just type two line in the textbox and press the submit button and see the result by yourself.

Much regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the html() method instead of text(). It will keep the formatting:

```
$('#button').on('click', function(){
    var text = $('#hey').html();
    $('#textspan').html(text);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zax8tkxq/

If you plan to save the results in a database and don't want to take care of the sanitization, then another option would be to use a textarea:

```
<span id="textspan"></span>
<textarea id="hey"></textarea>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Submit" />
```

And add the following CSS property to your container:

```
white-space: pre;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7ngurg3q/

Comment: Okay this worked fine, But there is not gonna be a problem if you retrieve the `#hey` value saved in my database, No XSS right?

Comment: I added an example if you don't want to sanitize html to your database

Comment: I'm so sorry for my late reply, Anyway the second example works fine but there u are using `textarea` can give the same kinda example for a `div` being `contenteditable`?